# Ajax login not reacting as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've a drop down login box.  A simple jquery function(below) toggles a slide on or off when pressed.

```
//Displaying the login dropdown menu
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#loginTrigger').click(function(){
    $(this).next('#loginContent').slideToggle();
})
});
```

I have an ajax function that checks login criteria etc.  The problem is that when a login is successful the login box doesn't roll back up and the login box doesn't change to profile as expected.

I think the latter is due to a php function that I have that checks if a user is logged in and displays the relevant links. Is there a workaround for this?  I essentially have something like

```
<?php if (loggedIn) ?>
Display these links
<?php else ?>
Display these other links.
```

The second query is the login box acknowledging a successful login and sliding back up.
I thought that by putting the code within the 'success' part it would work but I get an undefined message when trying to log in.  I'm pretty new to ajax and there's likely something very obvious I'm missing.

The ajax bulk - it reads in from a JSON to detrrmine errors or success.

```
beforeSend: function() {
        document.getElementById("statusLogin").innerHTML= 'checking...' ;
    },

    success: function(data) {

        $("#statusLogin").hide();

        if(data.success == true){

            $('#loginTrigger').click(function(){
                $(this).next('#loginContent').slideToggle();
            });

            alert("if data.success Area of Ajax");
            alert(data.message);

        }else{
            alert("data.message... " + data.message);//undefined
            $("#errorConsole").html(data.message);
        }

    },
    error:
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the toggle! :)

```
success: function(data) {

        $("#statusLogin").hide();

        if(data.success == true){

            $('#loginContent').slideToggle();


            alert("if data.success Area of Ajax");
            alert(data.message);

        }else{
            alert("data.message... " + data.message);//undefined
            $("#errorConsole").html(data.message);
        }

    },
    error:
```

Answer (score 0):

More success!!!

TO solve the issue with the user not being logged in I added

```
logginIn == true
```

at the end of the php file the ajax calls when a login is successful.  The links are not updated but I'm getting there.